# Logging in iptables

Tags: linux, security, debian, iptables, syslog

I have created rules in iptables to log and edited the rsyslog.conf file to output any message which contains "iptables" to a different log file. It seems that it is logging to both places, the default messages files and the new ip.log files i have. How can I log to just the new one? This is the content of the rsyslog file:

```
    :msg, contains, "iptables"      -/var/log/iptables.log 
    & ~
```

This is the rule I put into place in iptable:

```
    -I INPUT 1 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables in: "
```

Comment: One must place :msg, contains, "iptables"      -/var/log/iptables.log 
    & ~ at the start of rsyslog.conf and not at the end as I did

Answer (score 1):

The order of everything in the rsyslog.conf file matters. So one has to place the iptables criteria before rsyslog sees /var/log/messages. I put it at the start and it only logged to the new file.

(In case someone needs this for later :) )